# How to tell when wusa.exe has finished running?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

This question is sort of split between programming and sysadmin, so here goes:

I've got a PowerShell script which install dependencies for a piece of software. One of these dependencies is a .msu file. In my script, I invoke wusa.exe like such:

`"wusa.exe $DownloadDir\Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu /quiet /norestart"`

I've specified the `/quiet` switch as this is meant to be an silent/unattended installation.

However I can't seem to find any way to tell when wusa has finished executing as it appears to be running asynchronously.

Is this anyway to give an indication to my script when wusa.exe has either installed the hotfix and/or terminated?

Comment: Perhaps see [Difference between $? and $LastExitCode in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666035/difference-between-and-lastexitcode-in-powershell), and [Waiting in PowerShell for all child processes to finish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990488/waiting-in-powershell-for-all-child-processes-to-finish) over on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple Possible solutions to this:

**While Loops** can be used as a way of looking for a process, sleeping for a couple of seconds and then continue when a process is no longer present:

```
Do {
    sleep 2
    $instanceCount = (Get-Process | Where { $_.Name -eq "notepad" } | Measure-Object).Count
} while ($instanceCount -gt 0)
```

---

**Wait Job** can be used for starting a job and waiting for a job to complete:

```
$myJob = Start-Job -Name "MyJobName" -ScriptBlock { 
    #Do Something
 }
Wait-Job -Job $myJob
```

---

**Start Process** can also be used to start something and wait for it to complete:

```
Start-Process "C:\mything.exe arg1=something arg2=somethingelse" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Hopefully one of these will help you

Comment: Well this was solved in the comments 5 months ago. But hey.

Comment: Absolutely... but since I'm working towards a PowerShell MVP - I'm working my way througjh all the "Unanswered" stuff giving multiple solutions where I can.